# Why is my electric water heater not working?

Tags: water-heater

I have electric heating in my flat. My water is not heating up even though the timer light comes on and the immersion light comes on.

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

The element may need to be replaced

Comment: Can you explain how to troubleshoot the element issue?